# Optimizing Gallery for smooth scrolling

Tags: android, android-gallery

The code implemented below is used to display the picture gallery which is scrolled from left to rigth. But because I increased the size of the image thumbnail the scrolling has little glitch while scrolling. How can i smoothen up the scrolling any optimization needed.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView i = new ImageView(activity);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position]);
    i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400,400));
    i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    i.setImageBitmap(bmp);
    return i;
}
```

Comment: you must use lazy loading by decoding image in asynctask

Answer (score 0):

You need to write seperate thread to load and set bitmap for imageview.
Image loading and setting is a heavy task.

Comment: @Mayur create Async class. For this async class provide image view. After that onBackground method of asyc class load image from gallery. Then onPostExecute method set loaded image to the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath[position])` should not be on your main thread.

Do this work in 1 different thread. Queue up the decoding work and refresh the views with decoded images on the fly.

OR use a library like `picasso` that does this for you.

Comment: Can you provide a sample on how to use picasso library